# How to create new column in pandas dataframe of a calculation that happens to every other row except the one where the calculation will go into

Tags: python, pandas, drop

For example let's say I got dataframe df with series A.1 and A.2 like so:

```py
A.1    A.2
2      8
3      2
5      1
```

And I want to calculate let's say the difference of the means of all other rows like so:

```py
A.1    A.2    B
2      8      (3+5)/2 - (2+1)/2
3      2      (2+5)/2-(8+1)/2
5      1      (2+3)/2-(8+2)/2
```

My code looks like this and doesn't work, how should I write it correctly?

```py
df['B'] = mean(df['A.1'].drop(df['B'].index)))-mean(df['A.2'].drop(df['B'].index)))
```

I MUST totally avoid loops and do it in a panda-ish way as I'm working with huge datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.apply(lambda r : df.loc[df.index!=r.name,'A.1'].mean() - df.loc[df.index!=r.name,'A.2'].mean(), axis = 1)
```

result set is:

```
0    2.5
1   -1.0
2   -2.5
dtype: float64
```

Note that `r.name` inside lambda function is just index of current row.

Another approach with no lambda at all:

```
(df['A.1'].sum()-df['A.1'])/(len(df)-1) - (df['A.2'].sum()-df['A.2'])/(len(df)-1)
```

result is the same as above.

Comment: you sir are a god and a wizard of pandas! thank you!

Comment: Thanks, just added the alternative solution in advance :-)